# how to not load all tab in FragmentStatePagerAdapter

Tags: android, android-viewpager

i have a Page adapter that i called in activity,
it have 3 tabs , each tabs call a web service to full fill the ListView. besides, i have a sharedpreference to in every tabs.

the problem is, when i access the page from index, it took me a long time and in the log cat said that "I/Choreographer: Skipped 633 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread."

I assume its because they load the 3 tab at the same time, so the it make the process more hard. is there any way to do load tabs only whenever i clicked that tab ?

page adapter class

```
public class PagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
int mNumOfTabs;
private Context context;
public PagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, int NumOfTabs) {
    super(fm);
    this.mNumOfTabs = NumOfTabs;
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {

    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            MyRequest myReq = new MyRequest();
            return myReq;
        case 1:
            ListApproval myApp = new ListApproval();
            return myApp;
        case 2:
            ListApprovalHistory myAppHis = new ListApprovalHistory();
            return myAppHis;
        default:
            return null;
    }
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mNumOfTabs;
}
}
```

List Activity :

```
public class Workflow extends AppCompatActivity{
private static String URLService;
private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";
private static String userId;
private static String DirectSuperiorName;
private static String rowsPerPage;
private static SharedPreferences pref;

boolean _areLecturesLoaded = false;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.workflow_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);



        TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("My Request"));
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("My Approval"));
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("My Approval History"));
        tabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);

        final ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        final PagerAdapter adapter = new PagerAdapter
                (getSupportFragmentManager(), tabLayout.getTabCount());
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
        viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));
        viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(0);
        tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }
        });
    URLService = getString(R.string.URLService);
    getSuperior();
    //GET SESSION USERID
    pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MyPref", MODE_PRIVATE);
    userId = pref.getString("userId", "");
    rowsPerPage = pref.getString("rowsPerPage","");
    DirectSuperiorName = pref.getString("DirectSuperiorName","");
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_workflow, menu);
    return true;
}


@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        // Respond to the action bar's Up/Home button
        case android.R.id.home:

            Intent intent = new Intent(this, Index.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            return true;
        case 0:
            getSuperior();
            if(DirectSuperiorName != "") {
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
                editor.putString("PageType", "NewRequest");
                editor.commit();
                Intent i = new Intent(Workflow.this, WorkflowActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
            else
            {
                AlertDialog.Builder builder2 = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                builder2.setMessage("Cannot create new request, Please set DirectSuperior !")
                        .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            }
                        });
                builder2.create();
                builder2.show();
            }
            return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}



@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    menu.add(Menu.NONE,0,0,"Create  New").setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM);
    /*if(DirectSuperiorName != ""){
        menu.add(Menu.NONE,0,0,"Create New").setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM);
    }
    else{
        menu.clear();
    }*/
    return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
}


@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    Intent i = new Intent(this, Index.class);
    startActivity(i);
    super.onBackPressed();
}
}
```

this is my fragment child code:

```
public class ListApproval extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment {
private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";
private static String userId;
private static String rowsPerPage;
private SwipeRefreshLayout swipeContainer;
private List<ListApprovalItem> mItems;
private ListApprovalItem item;
private static SharedPreferences pref;
private Handler mHandler;
private static String URLService;
private String Enc_Pass="";
private boolean isDataLoaded;

// TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
public static ListApproval newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
    ListApproval fragment = new ListApproval();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}


public ListApproval() {
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_item_list_approval, container, false);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);

    this.mHandler = new Handler();
    this.mHandler.postDelayed(getData,500);
    URLService = getString(R.string.URLService);
    Enc_Pass = getString(R.string.password_encryption);
    //GET SESSION USERID
    pref = getActivity().getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MyPref", getActivity().MODE_PRIVATE);
    userId = pref.getString("userId", "");
    rowsPerPage = pref.getString("rowsPerPage","");

    final ListView lv = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.lvApproval);
            lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    new BigProccess(getActivity(), ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER).execute();
                    item = new ListApprovalItem();
                    item = mItems.get(position);
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
                    editor.putString("PermitID", item.permitid);
                    editor.putString("PageType", "MyApproval");
                    editor.putString("LeaveType", item.tipe);
                    editor.commit();

                    Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), WorkflowActivity.class);
                    getActivity().startActivity(i);
                }
            });

    getApprovalList(); // i call my api here , when oncreateview start

    if (mItems==null)
    {
      /*  Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Internet connection appears to be offline",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();*/

    }
    else
    {
        lv.setAdapter(new ListApprovalAdapter(getActivity(), mItems));
    }
    swipeContainer = (SwipeRefreshLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.swipeContainer);
    swipeContainer.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
        @Override
        public void onRefresh() {
            getApprovalList();

            if (mItems==null)
            {
              /*  Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Internet connection appears to be offline",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();*/

            }
            else
            {
                lv.setAdapter(new ListApprovalAdapter(getActivity(), mItems));
            }
            swipeContainer.setRefreshing(false);
        }
    });
    return view;
}


@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1)
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == 0) {
      /*  SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
        editor.putString("PageType", "ApprovalHistory");
        editor.commit();

        Fragment newFragment = ListApprovalReimbursementHistory.newInstance(6);
        FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.addToBackStack(null);
        ft.replace(R.id.flApproval, newFragment).commit();*/

    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
  //  getActivity().getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.index, menu);
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
}

@Override
public void onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
//    menu.clear();
  //  menu.add(Menu.NONE,0,0,"History").setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM);
    super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
}






private final Runnable getData = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        getApprovalList();
    }
};

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    // remove the dividers from the ListView of the ListFragment
    //getListView().setDivider(null);
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);

}
```

}

i am not sure where is the problem, 
can you guys help me ? 
any help would be appreciate

Comment: @Override
public int getCount() {
    return mNumOfTabs;
} Change this return to return 1

Comment: Or try setting the viewpager's offScreenLimit to 1

Answer (score 0):

One way is to override `setUserVisibleHint` method of `Fragment` - 
Adding piece of code how you should do that,

```
public class ListApproval extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment {

    private boolean isDataLoaded;

    public static ListApproval newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
       ListApproval fragment = new ListApproval();
       Bundle args = new Bundle();
       args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
       fragment.setArguments(args);
       return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                           Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_item_list_approval,  container, false);
       setHasOptionsMenu(true);

       // Do your UI related stuffs here...

       return view;
    }

    /*
    * Set a hint to the system about whether this fragment's UI is currently visible to the user.
    */
    @Override
    public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
        super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
        // isDataLoaded is to prevent multiple calls
        if (isVisibleToUser && !isDataLoaded ) {
           loadData(); // Make an api call to bind data into your list
           isDataLoaded = true;
        }
    }
}
```

More about `setUserVisibleHint()` [Click here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/Fragment.html#setUserVisibleHint(boolean))

Comment: hey thanks for answer, but where i can put the line code ? in my view pager or in my activity?

Comment: In your `Fragment` that is `MyRequest`, `ListApproval` and `ListApprovalHistory` in your code. I mentioned the comment over there and if there is still any confusion, click on the link and you will be redirected to Official Documentation of Android.

Comment: but i call my api service in oncreateview (as soon as the fragment starting) , is it will work in setuservisibilehint()?

Comment: No buddy, In your `MyRequest` class and your `ListApproval` class and your `ListApproval` class.

Comment: Edited my answer. Now you can get better Idea about how to load data when the fragment becomes visible to User.